# Allocating sufficient memory for unknown length tokens

Tags: c

For various reasons I won't discuss here, I am writing a simple tokenizer in C. Below is an example I hacked out which resizes the token buffer in predetermined increments as necessary when reading characters from the input stream. It will ultimately reach the size of the largest token which can obviously accommodate smaller tokens. Is this an acceptable approach? If not, what is the best way to determine the correct amount of memory to allocate for each token?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define BUFF_CHUNK_SIZE 4

int main() {
    int c, i, n;
    char *buffer;

    i = 0;
    n = BUFF_CHUNK_SIZE;
    buffer = (char *)calloc(n, sizeof(char));

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (isalnum(c)) {
            buffer[i] = (char)c;
            i++;
            if (i == n) {
                n += BUFF_CHUNK_SIZE;
                buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, n * sizeof(char));
            }
        }
        else {
            if (i == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            i = 0;
            printf("%s\n", buffer);
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(char) * n);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just checking: you know about `flex`, right?

Comment: In the branch where you call `realloc()`, the newly added memory has arbitrary content. In that case, the buffer may not be a properly null terminated string. Later, you do clear the whole buffer so the next token will be null terminated unless it too grew the buffer. Also, you never need to multiply by `sizeof(char)` which is by definition 1.

Comment: @Borealid, yes I am familiar with flex.  @RBerteig thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is pretty much the right approach - with two tweaks.

Firstly, instead of *adding* a constant `BUFF_CHUNK_SIZE`, it's usually better to *multiply* it by a fixed amount.  This means that your number of reallocs on a long string of length N becomes proportional to `log N` rather than `N` - meaning that the time spent in `realloc()` is proportional to `N log N` rather than `N`<sup>`2`</sup>.  It doesn't really matter what the constant is - 1.5 might be a good choice (`n += n / 2;`).

Secondly, in a longer program you should really check for `realloc()` failing.

Comment: Yeap, otherwise that code just wastes all the time reallocating and copying instead of doing real work. Also maybe the initial block size should be bigger - depending on how frequent are tokens of different lengths.

Comment: I know I shold be checking return of failed *allocs, but this was a quick and dirty mock up.  But taking the advice from @caf and previously @RBerteig I should resize like this, correct?

n *= 1.5;
buffer = (char *)realloc(buffer, n);
memset(buffer + i, 0, n - i);

Answer (score 0):

realloc was right, but you should use a char as token-separator?!

```
#define BUFF_CHUNK_SIZE 4
#define TOKSEP ";"

char *getOneToken(char *s,size_t n)
{
  int c;
  char *p=s;
  while( p-s < n-1 && !feof(stdin) && ((c=getchar())=='\n'?c=getchar():1) )
    if( isalnum(c) )
      *p++=c;
  *p=0;
  return s;
}

main() 
{
  char *buffer=calloc(1,1),
        tok[BUFF_CHUNK_SIZE+1];

  while( *getOneToken(tok,sizeof tok) )
  {
    buffer=realloc(buffer,strlen(buffer)+strlen(tok)+2);
    if( *buffer ) strcat(buffer,TOKSEP);
    strcat(buffer,tok);
  }

  puts(buffer);
  free(buffer);
  return 0;
}
```